# how to update record in between a file in python

Tags: python-3.x

We are trying to implement a file based student record program. We have implemented the reading and writing (Append Records) Functionalities. However now we are interested in updating a particular record via Student id. We have tried using the replace() function to replace the record but this ends up replacing all occurrences of the data in the file which makes it ambiguous.We have also tried over writing data using seek() but it does not helps much.example code is as follows.

```
import fileinput
import sys
for i,line in enumerate(fileinput('file_name.txt', inplace=1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('old','new')
```

Any help shall be great.

Comment: Your code is written to replace all occurrences of `old` with `new`. Shouldn't you do the replace only for the student id which you want to replace? Also you shouldn't use files for such cases. You should try other [data persistence](https://pymotw.com/3/persistence.html) options available in python

Comment: @clement i have tried what you suggested but when we do so it replaces all the data in the file with the new data , but what i want to do is replace the data of a particular student using its roll number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your input file is

```
1:Naveen Kumar:Chennai
2:Joseph Nirmal:Bangalore
```

and you want to change the name of student id `2` to `Joseph Nirmal Kumar`, then the following code should do

```
import fileinput
import sys
# change name for student 2
for line in fileinput.input('records.txt', inplace=1):
    id,name,location = line.split(':')
    if id == '2':
        sys.stdout.write('{}:{}:{}'.format(id,'Joseph Nirmal Kumar',location))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

then the file will become

```
1:Naveen Kumar:Chennai
2:Joseph Nirmal Kumar:Bangalore
```

Hope that helps. I would recommend to try other [data persistence](https://pymotw.com/3/persistence.html) options available in python